# Eclipse Phonegap Index file changes not appearing on build

Tags: android, eclipse, html, cordova

When I make any change to the index.html file in Eclipse, while using phonegap to export to Android applications, the change does not become visible on the device or simulator. Deleting the application is not the solution as it contains user data that is not possible to be deleted. I've googled the answer several times with several variations of the search, and the most common answer I see is to Refresh, Clean, Build, Deploy. This used to work, but now it does not. I've tried clearing the cache on the device for the application, but the lack of change still persists on deployment. Any help to get this issue resolved would be extremely helpful. (All I want to do is fix a stinking typo)

On a similar note, the changes I make to the same files in Xcode for the iOS version of my application take place instantly after Build and Archive, and are visible instantly on the device and simulator. I only experience the lack of change when doing it in Eclipse for Android.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, I did. It's actually really simple. I was making the changes to  www instead of assets/www

Comment: Half the time I don't know if my build includes the latest changes. Thanks for the reply.